# eclipse starts for some seconds and stop

Tags: eclipse

I suddendly start facing this bad problem

eclipse starts working and them after some seconds it stops.

i create a new eclipse `from unzipping the orginal eclipse` and i still have the same problem

when the eclipse stops, a new log file is automatilcally created in the eclipse directly.

this is what that log file states

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005ca3bb22, pid=6424, tid=3684
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x47bb22]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000008389000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3684, stack(0x00000000098c0000,0x00000000099c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000003091222, RBX=0x00000000099bcee0, RCX=0x000100000b7b1210, RDX=0x00000000099bcee0
RSP=0x00000000099bc9d0, RBP=0x00000000099bcb00, RSI=0x000000000b7b10e8, RDI=0x00000000099bca60
R8 =0x00000000000007eb, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x000000005cb3eea8, R11=0x00000000000000eb
R12=0x0000000009c7abf4, R13=0x0000000000000100, R14=0x000000000b940bf0, R15=0x00000000ffffffff
RIP=0x000000005ca3bb22, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000099bc9d0)
0x00000000099bc9d0:   00000000099bcb88 0000000003091220
0x00000000099bc9e0:   00000000000003a0 0000000000000000
0x00000000099bc9f0:   000000000b7b10e8 000000005c975a13
0x00000000099bca00:   0000000003091500 00000000099bf170
0x00000000099bca10:   00000000099bf170 000000000b7b10e8
0x00000000099bca20:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000099bca30:   000000005caba8d0 00000000099bcab8
0x00000000099bca40:   0000000003091220 00000000030914e0
0x00000000099bca50:   0000000003091220 00000000099bcb88
0x00000000099bca60:   000000005caa8700 00000000030915a0
0x00000000099bca70:   0000000000000000 00000000030915a0
0x00000000099bca80:   00000000030915c0 00000000030915c0
0x00000000099bca90:   00000000030915c0 0000000003091614
0x00000000099bcaa0:   00000000030915a0 000000005c000000
0x00000000099bcab0:   00000000099bca60 0000000003091220
0x00000000099bcac0:   0000000003091220 0000000003091223 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000005ca3bb22)
0x000000005ca3bb02:   eb 08 48 8b 47 68 41 80 cb e8 c6 00 c1 48 ff 47
0x000000005ca3bb12:   68 48 8b 47 68 44 88 18 48 ff 47 68 48 8b 4e 50
0x000000005ca3bb22:   48 8b 01 ff 50 30 48 8b 4f 68 48 8b 5c 24 30 48
0x000000005ca3bb32:   8b 74 24 38 88 01 48 ff 47 68 48 83 c4 20 5f c3 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000030911d0 [CodeBlob (0x00000000030911d0)]
Framesize: 0
BufferBlob (0x00000000030911d0) used for Compile::scratch_buffer
RBX=0x00000000099bcee0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000008389000
RCX=0x000100000b7b1210 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000099bcee0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000008389000
RSP=0x00000000099bc9d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000008389000
RBP=0x00000000099bcb00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000008389000
RSI=0x000000000b7b10e8 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000099bca60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000008389000
R8 =0x00000000000007eb is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000005cb3eea8 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000000000eb is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000009c7abf4 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000100 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000b940bf0 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000ffffffff is an unallocated location in the heap


Stack: [0x00000000098c0000,0x00000000099c0000],  sp=0x00000000099bc9d0,  free space=1010k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x47bb22]


Current CompileTask:
C2:  25098 1866   !         com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser::startElement (589 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000b839000 JavaThread "Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=6320, stack(0x00000000102b0000,0x00000000103b0000)]
  0x000000000b838800 JavaThread "Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=916, stack(0x00000000101b0000,0x00000000102b0000)]
  0x000000000b80f800 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=6488, stack(0x00000000100b0000,0x00000000101b0000)]
  0x000000000b80e800 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2276, stack(0x00000000109c0000,0x0000000010ac0000)]
  0x000000000b80e000 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5328, stack(0x00000000108c0000,0x00000000109c0000)]
  0x000000000b80d000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=6548, stack(0x00000000107c0000,0x00000000108c0000)]
  0x000000000b80c800 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5876, stack(0x00000000106c0000,0x00000000107c0000)]
  0x000000000b80b000 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3336, stack(0x00000000104c0000,0x00000000105c0000)]
  0x000000000b809800 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7100, stack(0x000000000fec0000,0x000000000ffc0000)]
  0x000000000b80b800 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=5848, stack(0x00000000105c0000,0x00000000106c0000)]
  0x000000000b80a000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6648, stack(0x000000000fdc0000,0x000000000fec0000)]
  0x000000000b808800 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4820, stack(0x000000000eaa0000,0x000000000eba0000)]
  0x000000000be1c800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6476, stack(0x000000000e9a0000,0x000000000eaa0000)]
  0x000000000a904000 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_in_native, id=872, stack(0x000000000d8d0000,0x000000000d9d0000)]
  0x000000000a90d000 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5372, stack(0x000000000c6c0000,0x000000000c7c0000)]
  0x000000000ac3c000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=6300, stack(0x000000000c3c0000,0x000000000c4c0000)]
  0x000000000b761800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7056, stack(0x000000000c2c0000,0x000000000c3c0000)]
  0x000000000a963800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6132, stack(0x000000000c1c0000,0x000000000c2c0000)]
  0x000000000a834800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4844, stack(0x000000000be40000,0x000000000bf40000)]
  0x000000000a4c1000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6216, stack(0x000000000ad70000,0x000000000ae70000)]
  0x000000000a4bc800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=7096, stack(0x000000000ac70000,0x000000000ad70000)]
  0x000000000839b000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3696, stack(0x00000000099c0000,0x0000000009ac0000)]
=>0x0000000008389000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3684, stack(0x00000000098c0000,0x00000000099c0000)]
  0x0000000008387800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5440, stack(0x00000000097c0000,0x00000000098c0000)]
  0x0000000008386800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4364, stack(0x00000000096c0000,0x00000000097c0000)]
  0x000000000837f000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5368, stack(0x00000000095c0000,0x00000000096c0000)]
  0x00000000029c5800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6368, stack(0x00000000094c0000,0x00000000095c0000)]
  0x00000000029be800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5640, stack(0x00000000093c0000,0x00000000094c0000)]
  0x00000000029dc800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3976, stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000082f2000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000092c0000,0x00000000093c0000] [id=6028]
  0x00000000083ae800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000009ac0000,0x0000000009bc0000] [id=1876]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 128640K, used 78311K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000ffbe0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 102400K, 57% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f8eedd98,0x00000000fb960000)
  from space 26240K, 73% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fe70c218,0x00000000fedc0000)
  to   space 27392K, 0% used [0x00000000fb960000,0x00000000fb960000,0x00000000fd420000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 65718K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 76% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e402da70,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 148800K, used 97115K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9150000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 148800K, 65% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d5ed6e48,0x00000000d9150000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005b60000,0x0000000005cf0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000054e0000

Polling page: 0x00000000003b0000

Code Cache  [0x0000000002aa0000, 0x0000000003190000, 0x0000000005aa0000)
 total_blobs=2542 nmethods=1732 adapters=758 free_code_cache=42413Kb largest_free_block=43096576

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 25.012 Thread 0x0000000008387800 1870             com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.ResourceValue::<init> (17 bytes)
Event: 25.012 Thread 0x0000000008387800 nmethod 1870 0x0000000002fdb390 code [0x0000000002fdb4c0, 0x0000000002fdb538]
Event: 25.012 Thread 0x0000000008387800 1871             com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.ResourceValue::getResourceType (5 bytes)
Event: 25.012 Thread 0x0000000008387800 nmethod 1871 0x0000000002fdb190 code [0x0000000002fdb2c0, 0x0000000002fdb318]
Event: 25.018 Thread 0x0000000008387800 1872             com.android.ide.common.resources.MultiResourceFile::addResourceValue (86 bytes)
Event: 25.026 Thread 0x0000000008387800 nmethod 1872 0x00000000030222d0 code [0x00000000030224c0, 0x0000000003022c00]
Event: 25.044 Thread 0x0000000008387800 1873             com.android.ide.common.resources.MultiResourceFile::updateResourceItems (142 bytes)
Event: 25.055 Thread 0x0000000008387800 nmethod 1873 0x00000000030a0f10 code [0x00000000030a1140, 0x00000000030a1af0]
Event: 25.055 Thread 0x0000000008387800 1874             java.util.EnumMap::access$600 (5 bytes)
Event: 25.056 Thread 0x0000000008387800 nmethod 1874 0x00000000030220d0 code [0x0000000003022200, 0x0000000003022258]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 15.097 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 116864K, used 30688K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fee20000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 90496K, 14% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f62828c0,0x00000000fadc0000)
  from space 26368K, 65% used [0x00000000fadc0000,0x00000000fbe958c0,0x00000000fc780000)
  to   space 26432K, 0% used [0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fee20000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 59553K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 69% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3a28750,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 147840K, used 88932K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9060000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 147840K, 60% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56d9398,0x00000000d9060000)
Event: 15.103 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 129472K, used 3574K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fef20000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 26432K, 13% used [0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fd7cd8e8,0x00000000fee20000)
  to   space 26944K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fd450000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 59553K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 69% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3a28750,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 147840K, used 88932K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9060000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 147840K, 60% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56d9398,0x00000000d9060000)
}
Event: 15.103 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=24 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 129472K, used 3574K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fef20000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 26432K, 13% used [0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fd7cd8e8,0x00000000fee20000)
  to   space 26944K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fd450000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 59553K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 69% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3a28750,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 147840K, used 88932K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9060000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 147840K, 60% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56d9398,0x00000000d9060000)
Event: 15.282 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 129472K, used 0K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fef20000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 26432K, 0% used [0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fee20000)
  to   space 26944K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fd450000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 58208K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 67% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e38d8098,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 149888K, used 88932K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9260000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 149888K, 59% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56d9358,0x00000000d9260000)
}
Event: 15.761 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=25 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 129472K, used 76199K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fef20000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 73% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f9fc9f40,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 26432K, 0% used [0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fd450000,0x00000000fee20000)
  to   space 26944K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fd450000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 58208K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 67% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e38d8098,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 149888K, used 89084K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9260000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 149888K, 59% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56ff1e8,0x00000000d9260000)
Event: 15.770 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=25 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 112000K, used 8954K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fedc0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 8960K, 99% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fc2bebb0,0x00000000fc2c0000)
  to   space 26240K, 0% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fedc0000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 58208K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 67% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e38d8098,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 149888K, used 89084K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9260000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 149888K, 59% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56ff1e8,0x00000000d9260000)
}
Event: 15.770 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=26 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 112000K, used 8954K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fedc0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 8960K, 99% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fc2bebb0,0x00000000fc2c0000)
  to   space 26240K, 0% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fedc0000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 58208K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 67% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e38d8098,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 149888K, used 89084K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9260000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 149888K, 59% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56ff1e8,0x00000000d9260000)
Event: 15.923 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=26 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 112000K, used 0K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fedc0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 8960K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fc2c0000)
  to   space 26240K, 0% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fedc0000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 65718K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 76% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e402da70,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 148800K, used 89084K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9150000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 148800K, 59% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d56ff028,0x00000000d9150000)
}
Event: 19.575 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=27 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 112000K, used 103040K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000fedc0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 103040K, 100% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000)
  from space 8960K, 0% used [0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fba00000,0x00000000fc2c0000)
  to   space 26240K, 0% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fedc0000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 65718K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 76% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e402da70,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 148800K, used 89916K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9150000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 148800K, 60% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d57cf2c8,0x00000000d9150000)
Event: 19.587 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=27 (full 5):
 PSYoungGen      total 128640K, used 19376K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000ffbe0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 102400K, 0% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000fb960000)
  from space 26240K, 73% used [0x00000000fd420000,0x00000000fe70c218,0x00000000fedc0000)
  to   space 27392K, 0% used [0x00000000fb960000,0x00000000fb960000,0x00000000fd420000)
 ParOldGen       total 86272K, used 65718K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5440000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 86272K, 76% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e402da70,0x00000000e5440000)
 PSPermGen       total 148800K, used 89916K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d9150000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 148800K, 60% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d57cf2c8,0x00000000d9150000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 23.711 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x000000000301b6d8
Event: 24.680 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002ecd6bc
Event: 24.690 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002ecd6bc
Event: 24.700 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002ecd6bc
Event: 24.701 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002ecd6bc
Event: 24.753 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000002cfd658
Event: 24.776 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -12 fr.pc 0x0000000003017de4
Event: 24.826 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000003164cb0
Event: 24.866 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -34 fr.pc 0x0000000003164cb0
Event: 24.909 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Uncommon trap -83 fr.pc 0x0000000002d25868

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 19.981 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65d63e0 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 19.981 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65d6850 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 19.985 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65f0898 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 19.985 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65f0cd8 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 19.985 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65f1250 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 19.985 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Threw 0x00000000f65f1690 at C:\jdk7u2_64p\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 23.699 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003160f07 to 0x000000000316234d
Event: 23.711 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000301a309 to 0x000000000301b6bd
Event: 24.776 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003017bcb to 0x0000000003017dc9
Event: 24.909 Thread 0x000000000a904000 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002d23539 to 0x0000000002d25859

Events (10 events):
Event: 24.893 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000003073010
Event: 24.893 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x0000000003090e50
Event: 24.893 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000030a0dd0
Event: 24.894 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000030d5210
Event: 24.894 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000030d8d10
Event: 24.894 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000030df010
Event: 24.894 Thread 0x0000000008389000 flushing nmethod 0x00000000030e8a90
Event: 24.897 Thread 0x0000000008387800 flushing nmethod 0x000000000310f4d0
Event: 24.909 Thread 0x000000000a904000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002d25868 sp=0x000000000d9cec00
Event: 24.909 Thread 0x000000000a904000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002ad9164 sp=0x000000000d9ceb78 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000044f000     E:\William\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
0x0000000077c90000 - 0x0000000077e39000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077b70000 - 0x0000000077c8f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefdea0000 - 0x000007fefdf0b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000077a70000 - 0x0000000077b6a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feffdf0000 - 0x000007feffe57000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x0000000000180000 - 0x000000000018e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe100000 - 0x000007fefe1c9000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007feffd50000 - 0x000007feffdef000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefc450000 - 0x000007fefc644000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe340000 - 0x000007fefe3b1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007feffa60000 - 0x000007feffa8e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe8d0000 - 0x000007fefe9d9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     E:\William\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835\eclipse_1503.dll
0x000007fefe9e0000 - 0x000007fefeabb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe0d0000 - 0x000007fefe0ef000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feffe70000 - 0x000007fefff9d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007fefcd30000 - 0x000007fefcd3c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefc7c0000 - 0x000007fefc816000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefeac0000 - 0x000007fefecc3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefdb10000 - 0x000007fefdb1f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefe030000 - 0x000007fefe0c9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007feffc70000 - 0x000007feffd47000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000000005c5c0000 - 0x000000005cccf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefb130000 - 0x000007fefb139000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefe2f0000 - 0x000007fefe33d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe0f0000 - 0x000007fefe0f8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefbd00000 - 0x000007fefbd3b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077e60000 - 0x0000000077e67000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000071800000 - 0x00000000718d2000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
0x0000000065900000 - 0x000000006590f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000005e5f0000 - 0x000000005e618000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000065860000 - 0x0000000065875000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd470000 - 0x000007fefd487000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefd170000 - 0x000007fefd1b7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcf10000 - 0x000007fefcf2e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefdbe0000 - 0x000007fefdbef000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000065840000 - 0x0000000065859000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\binx86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\943\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-4333.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\appOracle\product\11.2.0\client_2;C:\appOracle\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\OpenSSL\bin;E:\William\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
USERNAME=WilliamK
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8303600k(5555752k free), swap 16605356k(13414600k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_25-b17), built on Jun 21 2013 12:58:32 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Wed Feb 19 08:57:30 2014
elapsed time: 25 seconds
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of Eclipse bug reports for crashes in `CompilerThread1`, they are generally closed as a bug in the JVM. So possibly updating to the current 7.0_51 JVM would help.

Comment: You have a 64 bit JVM, are you also on a 64 bit os (probably) and 64 bit Eclipse?

Comment: @Fredrik yes everything is 64 bit

Comment: @greg-449 how could i update the jvm please?

Comment: Anything in the `workspace/.metadata/logs` file?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Windows user so I can't advise on the updating the JVM.